# .Net Core session is returning null on certain controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have tried to figure this issue out for the past 2 days, im passing in a username once a user has logged in.

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
private readonly ISession _session;

    public LoginController(IContracts contracts, ISystemUserDomain systemUserDomain, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateUser(LoginViewModel model)
    {
         var successfulLogin = await _contracts.AuthenticateUser(model.Username, model.Password);
         if (!successfulLogin)
         {
             ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Login details are incorrect";
             return View("~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml");
         }
         _session.SetString("SessionUsername", model.Username);
         return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", systemUsers);

    }
```

Im am then populate the view with the username, as soon I try to create a new user the the session data is now null, now im also going to say i have a delete and edit function which does not delete the session data.

```
    private void refreshSession()
    {
        var d = _session.GetString("SessionUsername");
        var t = ViewData["SessionDataUsername"];
        ViewData["SessionDataUsername"] = _session.GetString("SessionUsername");  
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> UserCreationSubmit (CreateNewUser newUser)
    {
        await _systemUserDomain.CreateUser(newUser);
        ViewData["DeleteFailed"] = false;
        refreshSession();
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", await UpdateViewList());
    }
```

Why would this method even null out or delete the session data?

Comment: Your AuthenticateUser method is not returning anything. Can you share your full method?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho Hi, I have edited the code showing the full method